# Azure restore bacpac which is created from other Azure account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

we were using Azure account and currently in the process of moving to German azure and got a trail account with German azure. When I try to restore the backup from which i took from old account i am not below error.

```
{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "The ImportExport operation with Request Id '79a09223-8ba8-426c-a8b6-72daf5fb70f9' failed due to 'Error encountered during the service operation. \r\n\tCould not read schema model header information from package.\r\n\t\tThe model version '3.5' is not supported.\r\n'.",
  "target": null,
  "details": [],
  "innererror": []
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide more detailed steps on how you get to the error above?

Answer (score 2):

This is Xiaochen from Microsoft SQL team. The DacFx version in German clusters is lower than the version in other public clusters. We are working on the upgrade right now. In the same time, you can use SqlPackage to import the data to German clusters:

sqlpackage.exe /Action:Import /tsn:< server_name > /tdn:< database_name > /tu:< user_name > /tp:< password > /sf:< source_file >

The latest version of DacFx/SqlPackage:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54106

More details about how to use SqlPackage to import data into Azure SQL Database